# Finding appropriate site for printing-technology question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**Update:**  The question has [now been posted](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/80413/57377) on the appropriate Stack Exchange.  Thank you!

---

I've a question on 2-D (on-paper) printing-technology question. What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask it?

---

## Help identify this map-printing technology.

Most old maps on my home (including few school-atlas and few professional-quality big maps from National Atlas of India), used a peculiar technology; where; instead the color-'dots'; used 'strokes' of continuous straight-lines oriented in different directions.

This one is portion of map of South America from a school-atlas published by a local publisher here (Kolkata) (Chandi Charan Das and co.,  150 Lenin sarani, kol-13. No mention of date or edition found however it is 15 to 20 yrs old book)

[image: Portion of south America from that school Atlas].

Scale:

[image]

The word Caracas ( "কারাকাস" ) on paper is approx 1.05 cm wide

On a Compound microscope (biology) (objective: 10X, Eyepiece 10X) but using reflected light; the lines does not show any 'dots' but uniform, continuous bands . The below-photograph is taken from another map (on Asia, topography) from the same book.

[image: Asia from that book; microscopy]

Left one shows some vertical and horizontal lines. Right-side-one shows some diagonal lines.

However the same school-atlas book used dot-printings too; in some-other maps; which are solely made with dot-method. no such 'solid' lines I yet found on these set of maps.

An old map by National Atlas of India, copyrighted as 1986; used similar pattern and probably same technology. But their grids are more fine (narrow and closely-placed).

[image]

Scale:

[image: scale]

The width of the word "Chamoli" on paper is approx 3.3 cm

Could anyone tell the identity of this beautiful old map-printing technology?

---

Suggested tags: Printing-techniques, Identification. Maps

Comment: This question also suits with [Geographic Information System SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) since that site is specified as "Q&A for **cartographers**, geographers and GIS professionals", and Engineering SE that deal with technologies. If it is a special [cartography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartography) technique then the first one is the correct site.

Comment: I'll wait 1 or 2 days if moderator teams wish to move it. Otherwise I'll copy-paste the content of this question to [Graphic Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartography) which includes print making.

Comment: A benefit of moderator's move is, this page will remain for certain times; so the people got a link to this page; could access this page and will be redirected to the moved question. But if right now I delete this question after copy-paste of the content at graphic-design site; the already-shared links to this page will become dead right-now.

Comment: I'm copy-pasting my question (after required edits) to Graphic design site; but not deleting this meta post right now. Moderators may close or delete or redirect as per their decision.

Comment: This question won't be moved. It's a question about **where to** ask this question, not an question. Also, since the question has been answered (and those answers have a positive score), you can not delete it (nor should you). I'm not sure why you seem so set on getting rid of this version of the question. It is unnecessary and inappropriate to do so.

Comment: what thing you are describing as "unnecessary and inappropriate"? I could not understand. Sorry not fluent in English

Comment: Moving or deleting the question is unnecessary and inappropriate.

Comment: Okay I'll keep in mind. Maybe I was thinking that way due to a high rate of closing and holding in stack sites. The site even awards badges like "peer-pressure" and ["disciplined"](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)

Comment: The actual question now has been **published [Here**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80413/please-help-to-identify-this-map-printing-technique) on graphic design site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this fits [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). I also think these people are the most capable of answering your question.

From [their help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Graphic Design** is for questions targeted toward design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Layout, printing and typography;

Comment: okay if it fits there; feel free to move there. However on same time it fits good with Engineering SE (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) since it is a technology question.

Comment: Possibly indeed. Your site recommendation question is okay here. Just post your question on the site of your choice.

Comment: Graphic design link you gave, is dead. did you tried to write `https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks actually before asking the question; I could not find a site on 2D-printing already exist. Probably I overlooked this site as computer-graphics or graphic-software.

Comment: What went wrong I dont know but site link was as long as `[1]: http://I%20think%20this%20fits%20Graphic%20Design.%20I%20also%20think%20these%20people%20are%20the%20most%20capable%20of%20answering%20your%20question.%20%20From%20[their%20help%20center] ``[1]:%20%20%3E%20**Graphic%20Design**%20is%20for%20questions%20targeted%20toward%20design%20professionals,%20students,%20and%20enthusiasts.%20%20%3E%20This%20includes%20questions%20about:%20%20%3E%20Layout,%20printing%20and%20typography;%20%20%20[1]:%20http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic` both linked to `[1]`

Comment: I'm copy-pasting my question (after required edits) to Graphic design site; but not deleting this meta post right now. Moderators may close or delete or redirect as per their decision

Comment: They won't. Why delete a useful question?

Answer (score 6):

Yes this would be in scope on [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).  We already have the tags:

- [maps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps)
- [print-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-design)
- [identity](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity)

A few interesting map questions:

- [How to create a map in Photoshop with hills?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57584/how-to-create-a-map-in-photoshop-with-hills)
- [Before computers, how did cartographers draw roads with perfectly parallel sides?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62086/before-computers-how-did-cartographers-draw-roads-with-perfectly-parallel-sides)

Before asking make sure you follow the guidelines:

- [What are the requirements for style identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930/)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's so much a style-id question as it is a technique-id question, wouldn't hurt to give the style-id guidelines a read though :)

Comment: I've given them a read through but we don't necessarily have a technique tag and technically some could argue this should go under the Style tag which is why I included it, doesn't hurt, just a good practice to reference if someone comes here and sees this question and wants to ask about maps.

Comment: We can always modify the style tag to include techniques for identification purposes or propose a new tag, the community is flexible.